# linux 32 bit assembly to C programming convertion

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

I want convert this asm code to C++ or C, I can understand the main concepts inside main like variable decleration and calling functions but I am stuck with push and pop commands and cant understand how they work.

```
    main:
   0x080489cc <+0>: lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x080489d0 <+4>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x080489d3 <+7>: push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x080489d6 <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x080489d7 <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x080489d9 <+13>:    push   ebx
   0x080489da <+14>:    push   ecx
   0x080489db <+15>:    sub    esp,0x10
   0x080489de <+18>:    call   0x80488b0 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
   0x080489e3 <+23>:    add    ebx,0xa261d
   0x080489e9 <+29>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x1
   0x080489f0 <+36>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],0x3
   0x080489f7 <+43>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],0x9
   0x080489fe <+50>:    sub    esp,0x4
   0x08048a01 <+53>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14]
   0x08048a04 <+56>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10]
   0x08048a07 <+59>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
   0x08048a0a <+62>:    call   0x8048a34 <blender>
   0x08048a0f <+67>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x08048a12 <+70>:    sub    esp,0x8
   0x08048a15 <+73>:    push   eax
   0x08048a16 <+74>:    lea    eax,[ebx-0x2ed18]
   0x08048a1c <+80>:    push   eax
   0x08048a1d <+81>:    call   0x804f100 <printf>
   0x08048a22 <+86>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x08048a25 <+89>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048a2a <+94>:    lea    esp,[ebp-0x8]
   0x08048a2d <+97>:    pop    ecx
   0x08048a2e <+98>:    pop    ebx
   0x08048a2f <+99>:    pop    ebp
   0x08048a30 <+100>:   lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
   0x08048a33 <+103>:   ret    

blender:
   0x08048a34 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x08048a35 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048a37 <+3>: call   0x8048a51 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax>
   0x08048a3c <+8>: add    eax,0xa25c4
   0x08048a41 <+13>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8] 
   0x08048a44 <+16>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc] 
   0x08048a47 <+19>:    add    eax,edx 
   0x08048a49 <+21>:    add    eax,eax 
   0x08048a4b <+23>:    imul   eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x10] 
   0x08048a4f <+27>:    pop    ebp
   0x08048a50 <+28>:    ret
```

Comment: Read about [stack on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) and come back and edit your post if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Inside main()
From 0x080489e9 to 0x080489f7 // declearing three 4 byte integers and initialise them with 1,3 and 9
we can assume this part as:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;
int c = 9;
```

From 0x08048a01 to 0x08048a0a // pushing variables from right to left to send them as argument to blender function, then calls blender
blender(a,b,c);

Inside blender()

```
 0x08048a41 <+13>:  mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8] // edx = 1
   0x08048a44 <+16>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc] // eax = 3
   0x08048a47 <+19>:    add    eax,edx // eax = eax+edx = 4
   0x08048a49 <+21>:    add    eax,eax //eax = 2*eax
   0x08048a4b <+23>:    imul   eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x10] //[ebp +0x10] = 9 imul means signed multiply so this means; eax = eax * 9 
        pop
```

something like

```
return 2*(a+b) *c // 2*(1+3) * 9 = 72
```

After blender call it calls 0x08048a1d <+81>:   call   0x804f100  function and prints the result, there is no other variable declaration between I think it is a direct call inside printf

```
prinf("%d" , blender())
```

final code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 9;

    printf("%d" , blender(a,b,c));
    return 0;
}

int blender(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return 2*(a+b) * c;
}
```

Comment: The multi-operand forms of `imul` like `imul r32, r/m32` aren't signed or unsigned specifically, they're both, like `add`.  Only the one-operand `mul r/m32` and `imul r/m32` are specifically unsigned or signed, because the upper half of the result (in EDX) differs.  This is why Intel didn't also make 2-operand or immediate versions of `mul`.

Comment: Yes, from the fact that this is clearly un-optimized compiler output, you're right that there's no temporary variable in the source for the `blender` result.  Otherwise it would be stored/reloaded.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the possibly-confusing `call   0x80488b0 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>` loads the thunk return address into EBX, and gcc is doing this because it was compiled with `-fPIE` to make a position-independent executable.  But 32-bit x86 doesn't support RIP-relative addressing.  This is a weird extra hurdle to give beginners in reverse-engineering; a normal executable built with `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie` would be better (even though that's not the default on modern Linux.)